# Emirates and Known Traveler Number: they want place of issue and date of issue. How/where do I get these?

Tags: emirates, global-entry, tsa-precheck

I booked a flight on Emirates from the USA to Europe and I want to provide them my GOES Known Traveler Number so I can use TSA PreCheck. But Emirates asked for the place and date of issue for my GOES Known Traveler Number.

How and where do I get the place of issue and date of issue for my GOES KTN? Is place of issue the street address where I got it or I can just give Emirates the city where I got it? If the info I give is not correct, is that bad? Could I get screened at the airport?

For USA-based airlines, I simply enter the Known Traveler Number and that's it. I'm TSA PreCheck ready. I have never been asked for anything more from a domestic USA airline. Why would an airline need more info than just the KTN (they also have my passport info)?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing the fields with Place of Issue and Date of Issue for you *Passport*?  KTN's do not have either of those.

Comment: I actually asked exactly that to the Emirates operator (I tried to do this on the phone since there were no options to enter a KTN on their site) and the operator said they need this info for the KTN. Odd I think but this is what they said they needed so not sure what to do. Has anyone flown Emirates from the USA and was able to use your KTN for TSA PreCheck? How did you do it?

Comment: I wonder if the Middle Eastern airlines have higher security checks for US flights.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/emirates-skywards/1818139-precheck.html) on flyertalk from last year, you can enter your KTN at online check-in. There is also a report of someone being asked for the KTN issue date on that thread. That user (aradisc) supplied the info and then subsequently reported entering the KTN at OLCI, so I suspect that it may not work trying to do this in advance. Since the issue date is not needed, you could just make one up if you want to try it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am a travel agent and I or should I say my clients have experienced this situation with Emirates only.  I enter the GOES (known traveler) number in the Sabre system but it is not acknowledged.  I was advised by two Emirates agents, including my company's dedicated representative that we have to call Emirates directly with the passenger GOES issuance date, city/state issuance, expiration date and passenger place of birth.  I agree that this is absurd but we are being held captive by their rules.